# utilities for transforming a collection of documents into LibSVM format

Tags: machine-learning, libsvm

I have two different folders, one is for positive class and another is for negative class. Each folder contains a collection of documents. Are there any utilities that can transform this training data set into LibSVM format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use scikit-learn to write a python script to do this. You can use the following utilities:

- [load_files](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.load_files.html) to load the text documents,
- [TfIdfVectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/feature_extraction.html#text-feature-extraction) to extract text features as `scipy.sparse` in memory matrices,
- [dump_svmlight](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/datasets/svmlight_format.py#L257) to save the resulting sparse matrices on disk using the svmlight format.